# Using typeid to check for template type

Tags: c++, templates, typeid

I would like to know if doing the following is safe:

```
template<class T>
void Parameters::add(Parameter<T> p)
{
   std::string sprobe("");
   int iprobe = 0;
   double dprobe = 0.;

   if (typeid(T) == typeid(sprobe))
     this->mstrings[p.name()] = p;

   if (typeid(T) == typeid(iprobe))
     this->mints[p.name()] = p;

   if (typeid(T) == typeid(dprobe))
     this->mdoubles[p.name()] = p;
}
```

I have a Class for storing parameters. It has 3 boost::unordered_map member variables for storing parameters of type int, double and std::string;

I created a template class Parameter.

I understand that if my Parameter is not one of the 3 types that I anticipated this will fail. But it is not a problem since I know that the Parameters can only be of these types.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It sounds like you want template specialization. Or even just overloading.

Comment: why don't you overload your function ?

Comment: I think that overloading would do the trick.
Thanks a lot

But is it safe to use typeid in this context ?

Comment: `typeid` is RTTI, it may not be enabled at all, also, it drops *cv* qualifiers

Comment: @PiotrS. So it is a No I suppose :) Thanks

Comment: BTW, your solution can be improved a little bit with this:
1) You don't need to set int iprobe = 0 to get a type_info of int. Just do typeid( int );
2) You can have only one unordered_map, and the value type make it a boost::any or std::any. That way you only will need one map to store them all.

Answer (score 5):

The code won't compile, but not because of `typeid`. The problem is that even with the correct `if`-clauses, the code of your method needs to be compiled - all of it. That is independent of whether or not a part of the code is executed (=evaluated) or not. This leads to the problem that if `T` is `int`, you still need to be able to compile the code for the other cases, e.g., this line:

```
this->mstrings[p.name()] = p;
```

The type of `mstrings` is very likely incompatible with passing `Parameter<int>` as `p`, hence you will get a compile error.

The solution is to use overloading where each method must only compile one case, but not the others, example for `int`:

```
void Parameters::add(Parameter<int> p)
{
    this->mints[p.name()] = p;
}
```

and likewise for the other cases.

Final note: Even if you use `typeid`, you don't need the probes. You can simply use `typeid(int)` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring whether that is a good programming practice or not ...

Your program is safe from the language point of view. Comparison of `type_info`, the valued returned by the `typeid` operator, is well defined in the standard:

> **18.5.1 Class type_info**
>
> ...
>
> `bool operator==(const type_info& rhs) const;`
>
> 2 **Effects:** Compares the current object with *rhs*.
>
> 3 **Returns:** `true` if the two values describe the same type.