# Translate generic method C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, generics, dynamic-cast

I have a generic method in C#:

```
public T GetComponent<T>() where T : Component {
    foreach (Component component in this.components)
        if (component is T c)
            return c;

    return default(T);
}
```

I want to translate it in C++:

```
template<typename T>
T* GameObject::getComponent() const {
    if (!std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value)
        return nullptr;

    for (auto i = this->components->begin(); i != this->components->end(); i++)
        if (typeid(*i) == typeid(T))
            return dynamic_cast<T>(*i);

    return nullptr;
}
```

But it seems like neither `typeid` nor `dynamic_cast` cannot deal with generic types. How can I achieve it?

**EDIT:**

```
Component* GameObject::getComponent(const type_info& type) const {
    for (auto i = this->components->begin(); i != this->components->end(); i++)
        if (typeid(*i) == type)
            return *i;

    return nullptr;
}
```

Possible usage:

```
cg::SpriteRenderer2D* renderer = (cg::SpriteRenderer2D*)getComponent(typeid(cg::SpriteRenderer2D));
```

The only problem is that there is no check if the passed type derives `Component`. Also I'm not sure if I have to dereference `i` two times so `typeid(**i)`. The first one from `iterator` to `Component*`. The second one from `Component*` to `Component`. Or I store a list of `Component&`.

Comment: What is the actual type of `i`?

Comment: `std::list<cg::Component*>::iterator`

Comment: You can write your C# method much more easily: `public T GetComponent<T>() where T : Component { return this.components.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault(); }`

Comment: What are storing in your array of `Component`?

Comment: @SomeBody I know but I rewrote it so that I have a guideline about what I have to cover in the c++ function. Also, OfType is a bit less efficient because it goes through the whole list, also if an element was found. :)

Comment: @ThomasCaissard Declaration from GameObject.h: `std::list<Component*>* components;`

Comment: @Matze: No, it doesn't go through the whole list, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq

Comment: Okay, then I was wrong. But the C# method works at least in comparison to the c++ function. And I need the c++ version

Comment: C++ doesn't have reified generics - so `typeid(T)` or `typeid(T*)` won't work the way you want them to - so implementing anything like `.OfType<T>()` in C++ will be very painful (see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873338/using-typeid-to-check-for-template-type ). You probably don't want to use RTTI either. So it's important that your `Component` type in C++ is self-describing.

Comment: If your C# code is meant to be implementing anything like `IServiceProvider` then please be-aware that it's an anti-pattern because you lose compile-time guarantees about what services (`Component` in your case) are available. This is why dependency-injection with individual ctor parameters wins-out over just injecting an `IServiceProvider` to every ctor.

Comment: I mean to say is that attempting to convert this C# into C++  the way you're doing it is like translating English into a different language by translating each word individually, ignoring global context and language-features. In order to provide a good answer we need to know what `getComponent()` is meant to do and how it's used - because I'm sure there's a better **idiomatic C++** way of achieving your desired end-result. I'm thinking you should be using strongly-typed object containers or something - doing casts in C++ is generally a bad idea because of the lack of RTTI and reflection.

Comment: What about the edit? No generics, no casting

Comment: Maybe you already noticed that the naming is similar to unity's hierarchy. I wanted to try to implement a simple gameobject-component hierarchy like in unity.

Comment: Of cause I know what `is` does and of cause I know that my 'solution' in the edit is not similar to `is` because it's not looking at the inheritance tree. It's just a working type comparison with my c++ knowledge because it seems like I cannot pass the information necessary for a `dynamic_cast` as parameters or template types.

Comment: @matze Just completely ditch your “get component” concept and instead expose strongly-typed objects via distinct getters (and repetition in code can be solved with macros and other code-gen solutions). My rule of thumb is that if you have to up-cast an object-pointer anywhere then you’re doing something wrong (and that includes casting to a template parameter type)